# PostMessage failing to send keystrokes

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I have written a small global hook to be able to process keyboard as well as mouse input. I would like to be able to output a keystroke when the mouse is moved but so far I have been unable to get my keystrokes to send to any top level window. The only thing I have I can think it would be is my bits being correct as the lParam of PostMessage() but I have read over the docs and it seems this should be the correct order. I have tried it in notepad, chrome, microsoft word and a few other programs and haven't been able to get it to work so I'm lost.

Here is what I have so far

```
HHOOK hMouseHook;
MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT previousMouseEventData;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD dwThread;

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)setHooks, (LPVOID)argv[0], NULL, &dwThread);



    if (hThread)
        return WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
}

DWORD WINAPI setHooks(LPVOID lpParm)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (!hInstance) 
        hInstance = LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)lpParm);
    if (!hInstance) 
        return -1;


    hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, (HOOKPROC)MouseEvent, hInstance, NULL);
    MessageLoop();


    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);
    return 0;
}

void MessageLoop()
{
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
}
```

-As far as I can see this should be working

```
_declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK MouseEvent(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
{
    try {
        MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT newMouseEventData = *(MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

        if (newMouseEventData.hwnd == previousMouseEventData.hwnd &&
            newMouseEventData.pt.x != previousMouseEventData.pt.x)
        {
            int xChange = newMouseEventData.pt.x - previousMouseEventData.pt.x;
            //Mouse movement left
            if (xChange < 0)
            {
                cout << "Mouse left" << endl;


                //A press down
                //0 1 0 0 0000 01100001 0000000000000000
                int keydownLparam = 0b01000000011000010000000000000000;

                if (!PostMessage(newMouseEventData.hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x41, keydownLparam))
                {
                    cout << GetLastError() << endl;
                }

            }

        }
            else 
            {
                cout << "Mouse right" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(exception e){
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't fake input with PostMessage.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me don't all windows processes use the message queue? If so why wouldn't this work? Also how do you do it properly if not this way.

Comment: Typically using SendInput, but even then some programs won't respond to that. This topic is covered many times every day here on SO.

Comment: Is there a way to guarantee that what I send is processed via the receiving app?

Comment: Not likely. Why do you have such a hacky approach anyway. Faking input is really the last resort. What led you this way?

Comment: I'm making an 'external assistance' program for an online game I play, there's really no other way to go about it without bypassing its anticheat or I'd be doing that.

Comment: If SendInput fails to work I will most likely be writing a kernel mode driver so I can bypass the anticheat without having much problems, thank you for the information.

Comment: Games are notoriously hard to trick like this. They tend to defend against programs such as yours, to protect against cheating.

Comment: Exceptions should usually not be caught by value. Prefer catching by `const &`.

Comment: Would either of you know why visual studio 2015 is not recognizing SendInput or any of the structures needed even if I have user32.lib linked properly?

Comment: "That doesn't make sense to me..." The answer is the message queue is not a literal message queue; some of the messages that get received are in fact simulated by the queue itself. Some of that simulation involves the keyboard state; some of it involves input method editors and Text Services. [More info here.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) Of course, game automation is much harder, as noted. And yes, this is not an uncommon topic to ask about. As for VS2015, make sure you are including the right headers and setting version macros properly.

Comment: Don't use PostMessage. SendInput should be fine. If they don't process it, then that means they are using GetAsyncKeyState instead of listening for mouse events. You can use an IPC mapping and a hook to inject key-states in that case. Quite a bit more difficult actually.

Comment: @Brandon Or raw input, or something else